# Working with PPM image as an int *img

Tags: c, char, int, mean

I've been trying to implement the MSF using a grayscale PPM image and a template. I need to declare the image as "*int" img instead of unsigned char *img. But when I compute the zero-mean center at the template, I get values that doesn't make any sense. I tried unsigned char* and it gives the right pixel values before the zero-mean center and wrong after because 'unsigned char' does't have enough 'space' and doesn't accept negative values but at least it's consistent values. I know it's a silly mistake but I'm stuck on it. Could anyone help me on how could I implement it using int*? Thanks

Below is part of my code and both results

```
FILE *fpt1, *fpt2, *fpt3;
int *img, *gt, *int;
char    header[320], header2[320];
int COLS, ROWS, BYTES, COLS2, ROWS2, BYTES2, i, len;
int r , c, count, sum;

   /*Read template*/
fpt2 = fopen("parenthood_e_template.ppm", "r");
if (fpt2 == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open template of parenthood.ppm for reading\n");
    exit(0);
}
fscanf(fpt2,"%s %d %d %d\n", header2, &COLS2, &ROWS2, &BYTES2);
if (strcmp(header2, "P5") != 0 || BYTES2 != 255){
    printf("Not a template for parenthood.ppm\n");
    exit(0);
}

    /*Allocate memory for template*/
temp = (int*) calloc (COLS2*ROWS2, sizeof(int));

    /* Copy template into memory*/
header2[0] = fgetc(fpt2);
fread(temp,1,COLS2*ROWS2,fpt2);
fclose(fpt2);

              /* Matched Spatial-Filter */
    /* zero-mean the template*/
sum=0;
count=0;
for (r=0; r<ROWS2; r++) {
    for (c=0; c<COLS2; c++) {
        sum += temp[r*COLS2+c];
        printf("temp[%d]= %d\n", count, temp[r*COLS2+c]);
        count += 1;
    }
}

sum = sum/126;
```

The result for char*

```
    temp[0]= 199
    temp[1]= 196
    temp[2]= 199
    temp[3]= 198
    temp[4]= 198
    temp[5]= 199
    temp[6]= 199
    temp[7]= 202
    temp[8]= 197
    temp[9]= 196
    temp[10]= 195
    temp[11]= 198
    temp[12]= 200
    temp[13]= 197
    temp[14]= 199
    temp[15]= 199
    temp[16]= 198
    temp[17]= 195
    temp[18]= 196
    temp[19]= 196
    temp[20]= 199
    temp[21]= 197
    temp[22]= 198
    temp[23]= 196
    temp[24]= 196
    temp[25]= 193
    temp[26]= 194
    temp[27]= 195
    temp[28]= 193
    temp[29]= 155
    temp[30]= 133
    temp[31]= 150
    temp[32]= 187
    temp[33]= 196
    temp[34]= 196
    temp[35]= 195
    temp[36]= 192
    temp[37]= 109
    temp[38]= 69
    temp[39]= 105
    temp[40]= 88
    temp[41]= 78
    temp[42]= 184
    temp[43]= 194
    temp[44]= 193
    temp[45]= 145
    temp[46]= 74
    temp[47]= 177
    temp[48]= 189
    temp[49]= 186
    temp[50]= 100
    temp[51]= 105
    temp[52]= 191
    temp[53]= 191
    temp[54]= 72
    temp[55]= 139
    temp[56]= 191
    temp[57]= 192
    temp[58]= 188
    temp[59]= 168
    temp[60]= 46
    temp[61]= 183
    temp[62]= 186
    temp[63]= 43
    temp[64]= 89
    temp[65]= 110
    temp[66]= 114
    temp[67]= 114
    temp[68]= 107
    temp[69]= 37
    temp[70]= 176
    temp[71]= 191
    temp[72]= 43
    temp[73]= 126
    temp[74]= 133
    temp[75]= 133
    temp[76]= 137
    temp[77]= 129
    temp[78]= 132
    temp[79]= 187
    temp[80]= 191
    temp[81]= 52
    temp[82]= 167
    temp[83]= 188
    temp[84]= 192
    temp[85]= 195
    temp[86]= 195
    temp[87]= 195
    temp[88]= 191
    temp[89]= 189
    temp[90]= 94
    temp[91]= 108
    temp[92]= 189
    temp[93]= 193
    temp[94]= 192
    temp[95]= 191
    temp[96]= 192
    temp[97]= 192
    temp[98]= 193
    temp[99]= 173
    temp[100]= 49
    temp[101]= 141
    temp[102]= 175
    temp[103]= 177
    temp[104]= 108
    temp[105]= 125
    temp[106]= 195
    temp[107]= 199
    temp[108]= 197
    temp[109]= 163
    temp[110]= 90
    temp[111]= 70
    temp[112]= 75
    temp[113]= 109
    temp[114]= 180
    temp[115]= 191
    temp[116]= 194
    temp[117]= 197
    temp[118]= 193
    temp[119]= 192
    temp[120]= 185
    temp[121]= 188
    temp[122]= 195
    temp[123]= 196
    temp[124]= 195
    temp[125]= 0
    C= 9  R= 14
    temp = 35   mean=161
```

And the result for int*

```
    temp[0]= -959986489
    temp[1]= -892876858
    temp[2]= -960248635
    temp[3]= -943209016
    temp[4]= -993737786
    temp[5]= -993606201
    temp[6]= -1010646588
    temp[7]= -1769628735
    temp[8]= -1010514757
    temp[9]= 1766157760
    temp[10]= -1028108712
    temp[11]= -1320513087
    temp[12]= 1768209085
    temp[13]= -1958166593
    temp[14]= -1464024897
    temp[15]= 733656878
    temp[16]= 1920101977
    temp[17]= -1078975125
    temp[18]= -2054848981
    temp[19]= -1148943991
    temp[20]= -1129892673
    temp[21]= -1010580544
    temp[22]= 1818148287
    temp[23]= -1077886531
    temp[24]= -1379811136
    temp[25]= -1313895119
    temp[26]= -943489684
    temp[27]= 1180345285
    temp[28]= -1078694581
    temp[29]= -1061042750
    temp[30]= -993805127
    temp[31]= 195
    temp[32]= 0
    temp[33]= 0
    temp[34]= 0
    temp[35]= 0
    temp[36]= 0
    temp[37]= 0
    temp[38]= 0
    temp[39]= 0
    temp[40]= 0
    temp[41]= 0
    temp[42]= 0
    temp[43]= 0
    temp[44]= 0
    temp[45]= 0
    temp[46]= 0
    temp[47]= 0
    temp[48]= 0
    temp[49]= 0
    temp[50]= 0
    temp[51]= 0
    temp[52]= 0
    temp[53]= 0
    temp[54]= 0
    temp[55]= 0
    temp[56]= 0
    temp[57]= 0
    temp[58]= 0
    temp[59]= 0
    temp[60]= 0
    temp[61]= 0
    temp[62]= 0
    temp[63]= 0
    temp[64]= 0
    temp[65]= 0
    temp[66]= 0
    temp[67]= 0
    temp[68]= 0
    temp[69]= 0
    temp[70]= 0
    temp[71]= 0
    temp[72]= 0
    temp[73]= 0
    temp[74]= 0
    temp[75]= 0
    temp[76]= 0
    temp[77]= 0
    temp[78]= 0
    temp[79]= 0
    temp[80]= 0
    temp[81]= 0
    temp[82]= 0
    temp[83]= 0
    temp[84]= 0
    temp[85]= 0
    temp[86]= 0
    temp[87]= 0
    temp[88]= 0
    temp[89]= 0
    temp[90]= 0
    temp[91]= 0
    temp[92]= 0
    temp[93]= 0
    temp[94]= 0
    temp[95]= 0
    temp[96]= 0
    temp[97]= 0
    temp[98]= 0
    temp[99]= 0
    temp[100]= 0
    temp[101]= 0
    temp[102]= 0
    temp[103]= 0
    temp[104]= 0
    temp[105]= 0
    temp[106]= 0
    temp[107]= 0
    temp[108]= 0
    temp[109]= 0
    temp[110]= 0
    temp[111]= 0
    temp[112]= 0
    temp[113]= 0
    temp[114]= 0
    temp[115]= 0
    temp[116]= 0
    temp[117]= 0
    temp[118]= 0
    temp[119]= 0
    temp[120]= 0
    temp[121]= 0
    temp[122]= 0
    temp[123]= 0
    temp[124]= 0
    temp[125]= 0
    C= 9  R= 14
    temp = -8605725   mean=8605725
```

Comment: `unsigned char` would be the correct type in the first place. If you need to convert this to a more structured type, you have to de-serialize properly.

Comment: Note: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: You are reading 4 `byte` pixels into a single `int` pixel.

Comment: Your code does not read [PPM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) correctly.  In particular, PPM represents each pixel with either 3 bytes or 6 bytes, as indicated by the header field you are reading into variable `BYTES2`.  I don't know any system on which an `int` is either of those widths.  Moreover, reading the pixels as type `int` sets you up for byte-order issues.  You need a richer data type to represent PPM internally, and smarter code to read and process it.  Why not peruse (or use) NetPBM's own code?  It's open source.

Comment: @gre_gor yeah. I haven't realized that. But how could I assign 1 byte pixel per int pixel? Thanks!